# exposed loophole in google oauth

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

I am building a web app that includes multiple pages of markup.  Currently, I have implemented Google OAuth2 (using Python) for the main page that will be hit by users and it works like a charm.  However, I found a loophole that bypasses the OAuth2 login screen/verification:  Simply by adding an extension  to the end of the URL (say, "/index"), you can access the other pages within the app and completely bypass the OAuth login. I am looking for an easy way to include all of my different HTML pages in OAuth2 so anytime one of the app's pages is initially hit, the user will have to authenticate. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with google's python/web platform, but I suspect you're not applying the authentication requirement to the sub-pages. For example, are you enforcing authentication on the '/index' uri?

Comment: I thought about that, however in the Google Developers Console (where I register my redirect and js origin URI's) they restrict JavaScript origins so that they cannot be wildcards OR in my case paths (exp: cannot add "/index" to the end of the JavaScript origin).

Comment: Is it possible they expect you to specify each URI independently?

Comment: That was an option that crossed my mind, but I would get stuck at the "no paths in the JavaScript origin" issue again since the origin I would need to enter would be something like "mySite.com/index".

Comment: "Javascript origins" is meant por hostnames, not full paths. Thus, "no paths in the JavaScript origin". There is nothing in the Cloud Console that will help you to fix this problem. It's already working. Instead look for enforcing OAuth2 check/auth in every page.